# How can find which Duplo sets, featuring car base, are currently sold in France?

Tags: shopping, duplo

My son have been playing a lot with my old LEGO at his grandma's, and I would like to buy him some to play at home.

I have tried to figure this out on my own, but I am stuck :(

I have read inside the vehicle the part number, 2312, and found it on [Brinklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2312c01#T=C). It looks like it is retired, but the same mould tool got me to part [11248](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11248c01#T=C) which looks current.

It is in a decent number of sets, and I tried to find a few on the Internet, but it looks like they are retired. (Besides the obvious animal train, released this year)

How can I figure out, in the [set list](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=11248c01&in=S) which are sold, in France, today, without checking one by one?

Comment: If you're interested in other car bases, there's also this one that comes in a bunch of recent sets, and some of them have a nice vehicle/plane top too: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=12591c05&in=S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Life cycle of a set from standard/general LEGO themes is, usually, 2 years. There are exceptions of course, where availability could be shorter or longer, but usually it stays within that time period. Some toy shops could have these sets for an extended period of time, while supply lasts.

It isn't easy to find which sets are available for sale using Bricklink, since it has so many [Duplo Car Bases](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Duplo%20Car%20Base%202%20x%206&rpp=50&tab=P#T=P). So it would be much easier to check which Duplo sets are available for sale at [official LEGO online store](https://www.lego.com/fr-frb/themes/duplo).

Currently, following Duplo sets feature car bases:

- [Mickey & Minnie Birthday Train (10941)](https://www.lego.com/fr-fr/product/mickey-minnie-birthday-train-10941)
- [Animal Train (10955)](https://www.lego.com/fr-fr/product/animal-train-10955)
- [Number Train - Learn To Count (10594)](https://www.lego.com/fr-fr/product/number-train-learn-to-count-10954)
- [Unicorn (10953)](https://www.lego.com/fr-fr/product/unicorn-10953)